# What monitor to buy for the video card "Intel HD Graphics 4400"?

Tags: mice, video-adapters, mouse-pad

I'm buying a new monitor for a system using the video card "Intel HD Graphics 4400".  (I'm thinking about buying this [DELL S3422DW](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-34-curved-monitor-s3422dw/apd/210-axns/monitors-monitor-accessories). I'm wondering how good of a monitor I can buy that will be decently supported by this video card.

I did a test using a large monitor and the video card seemed to display okay at a resolution of `3840 x 2160`.  However, I noticed the mouse seemed to have a delay.  I don't own the monitor, so I can't easily test it again --- it didn't occur to me then to try to see if there was something wrong with the surface where I was sliding the mouse on.  I did a second test using another mouse --- a wireless one and I did use a mousepad that's usually used by it --- and I saw the same delay.

I was wondering --- could it be that the mouse is drawn by the video card and somehow it is slow at those high resolutions?  (Or was the optical mouse just in a bad surface for it?)

I have a 46" TV at home and the video card is able to get `1980 x 1080` on this TV.  I don't see a delay in the mouse at all.  (But could it happen at `3840 x 2160`?  Does that make sense?  I have no idea.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more pixels you have to draw, the more work has to be done by both CPU & GPU.

The Intel HD 4400 was not a 'good' GPU when new & is now a 10-year-old design [no longer supported by Intel or Microsoft]. It's an on-chip device which was used on Intel CPUs for a couple of years between 2013 & 2015. To know more detail we'd need to know the exact CPU model number.

There is a *big* difference in the amount of processing needed to power an "HD" display compared to a "4k". The display you propose is going to fall somewhere between these - however, a bigger issue night be in whether the GPU supports an ultrawide [WQHD 3440 x 1440 @ 100Hz] configuration at all. I very much doubt it will be able to run it at 100Hz.
It would be wise to research not only what maximum resolutions your computer supports, but also whether there is support for this type of ultrawide display at all.

You may be better off looking at a more 'regular' 2k configuration - a 27" 2560x1440 display for instance.